# Date formatting

Tags: java, date, formatting

I have the following date format I need to parse:

```
Aug  6, 2013 18:34:16.990423000
```

So I tried the following:

```
Date startTime;
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd, yyyy kk:mm:ss.S", Locale.ENGLISH);
startTime = df.parse("Aug  6, 2013 18:34:16.990423000");
```

But then `mydate.toString` gives me completely other date!

It gives me `"Sun Aug 11 11:27:43 IDT 2013"`!

Does it relate to time zone?

By the way, when I perform

```
ts = returnTime.getTime() - startTime.getTime();
```

it seems to return the correct answer. But I am not sure it is always so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with the `S` which indicates milliseconds. It adds that number of milliseconds to the date but you have 990423000 milliseconds. You might want to leave out the `.S` of your format or truncate your input first as in the following example:

```
Date startTime;
String dateString = "Aug  6, 2013 18:34:16.990423000";
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd, yyyy kk:mm:ss.SSS", Locale.ENGLISH);
startTime = df.parse(dateString.replaceFirst("\\.(\\d{3})\\d*$", ".$1"));
System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd, yyyy kk:mm:ss.SSS").format(startTime));
```

Comment: First of all, thanks a lot. This reg exp solution is defintely something a little advanced for me. But, it defiently worked. I still don't understand what was wrong with the formatting? Did I had to leave only 3 digits in the milliseconds place? Is that the issue? Because I guess it is like in other examples I saw.

Comment: Yes milliseconds may only be 3 digits. `SimpleDateFormat.parse` takes more digits when present but does interpret them as full milliseconds - not nanoseconds.